# How to remove the field's separator that ended on each last line?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl

How to remove the "," field's separator that ended on each last line?
by `sed`/`awk`/`perl` one linear

Example of csv file :

```
zoo.cfg,autopurge.purgeInterval,24,
zoo.cfg,autopurge.snapRetainCount,30,,,,
zoo.cfg,clientPort,2181,
zoo.cfg,dataDir,/var/hadoop/zookeeper,
zoo.cfg,initLimit,10,,
zoo.cfg,syncLimit,5,1,1,,
zoo.cfg,tickTime,2000,,,,,,,,,,
```

expected output:

```
zoo.cfg,autopurge.purgeInterval,24
zoo.cfg,autopurge.snapRetainCount,30
zoo.cfg,clientPort,2181
zoo.cfg,dataDir,/var/hadoop/zookeeper
zoo.cfg,initLimit,10
zoo.cfg,syncLimit,5,1,1
zoo.cfg,tickTime,2000
```

- target -  remove the unnecessary ended field separator "," or ",," or ",,," etc on each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ sed 's/,,*$//' input
```

This will replace all commas at the end of the line with nothing (they will be deleted).

`,,*$` will match one or more commas at the end of the line (literally "one comma and then zero commas or more").

The other way to do it is to correct the thing that *produces* the data so that it doesn't output empty fields.

Comment: I see two separators - but it could be one or two or more

Comment: @yael The pattern matches one or more commas.

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed`:

```
sed 's/,*$//' infile
```

this will match zero or more commas at the end of each line. With some `sed` implementations, you may tell `sed` to match one or more at the end with:

```
sed 's/,\+$//' infile
```

(the portable/standard equivalent being `,\{1,\}`, so you might as well use `,,*` or `,*` which would do the same).

Or with GNU `grep` or compatible:

```
grep -o '.*[^,]'
```

This will print only `-o` everything until last non-comma (would have the side effect of removing empty  lines though).

Or with GNU `awk` or `mawk`:

```
awk '1' RS=',*\n'  #or
awk '1' RS=',+\n'
```

This is defining **R**ecord **S**eperator as regex of `,*\n` (zero more commas or `,+\n` (one or more comas) till `\n`ewline seen.

The `1` is there is just a *always true* condition and it will cause to print the records and ignoring **RS**.

Or in `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/,*$//' #or
perl -pe 's/,+$//'
```

Comment: can simplify the grep regex: taking advantage of greediness we can do `grep -o '.*[^,]'` -- that's everything up to the last non-comma

Comment: Your perl solution looks the same as your sed solution. I don't know about perl. Can a sed command often be used without change in perl? Can a awk command also be used without change in perl? Is the syntax of perl more close to the syntax of sed command  than to the syntax of awk?

Comment: The origin of perl was in part inspired by both sed and awk. Older perl distributions contained programs `a2p` and `s2p` which could convert awk or sed scripts to perl.

Comment: @glennjackman Nice to know. Actually my question was more about learning perl: suppose I start to learn Perl, from which can I draw more of my experiences so that I can learn faster, awk or sed?

Comment: Probably your awk experience will help you a bit. But you should go into perl with fresh eyes. I really only use sed for very simple text transformations (`s///`, `d`, `a` or `i` occassionally): if the task is a bit more complicated, I go to awk which is very readable. If I need to solve a problem that is more complex than comfortably fits in awk, then I'll go to perl. Nogte that the three tools all use different flavours of regular expressions, with perl's being the most capable.

Comment: in summary, for me, sed is for quick transformation; awk is for data-driven problems; perl is for general purpose programming.